# Generate large numbers for interval

Tags: c++, c++11

I need to randomly produce two numbers L and R such that 1 ≤ L ≤ R ≤ 10^18.
How this can be done ? Please help.

My Code :

```
#define MAXN 1000
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    int x=rand()%MAXN;
    int y=rand()%100000;
    int z=rand()%100000;
    long L =x; 
    long R=x*y*z;
    assert(L<=R && L>=1 && L<=1000000000000000000 && R>=1 && R<=1000000000000000000); 
    cout<<L<<" "<<R<<"\n";
}
```

Obviously its not right way. So i am looking for best way to do it.

Approach 2 :

```
        const long min = 1;
        const long max = 1000000000000000000;

        std::default_random_engine generator(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<long> distribution(min,max);
        long L = distribution(generator);

        const long min1 = L;
        const long max1 = 1000000000000000000;
        std::default_random_engine generator1(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<long> distribution1(min1,max1);
        long  R = distribution1(generator1);
        assert(L<=R && L>=1 && L<=1000000000000000000 && R>=1 && R<=1000000000000000000); 
        cout<<L<<" "<<R<<"\n";
```

Comment: a) Use a variable type that can hold such large numers. `unit64_t`. b) Use a better generator. See the `<random>` include. As you do it now, it´s no uniform distribution, not even close.

Comment: @deviantfan Something like this ?

Comment: I repeat: `a) Use a variable type that can hold such large numbers.` How big is your `long`? And, your literals will need a `ULL` etc.etc

Comment: @deviantfan long can store upto 10^18. Thats not problem

Comment: @deviantfan But is this way right enough ?

Comment: Something wrong with just [doing **this**](http://ideone.com/92888w) ? I don't see why there would be a need to set up two distributions.

Comment: You need to give more thought to what distribution you want.  The fact that you want to produce two numbers with a built in relationship, inherently means at least one of them won't have a uniform distribution.  But your sample code (if tweaked to be correct, which it is not yet) would have a stranger and limited distribution that I think you don't want.  Even starting over from scratch, there is no correct answer until you decide on a possible desired distribution.

Comment: @WhozCraig  That is certainly the idea that leaps to mind when an experienced programmer looks at the question.  My math is not good enough to say what distribution you get from doing that.  But my math is good enough to see that after the swap neither number is uniformly distributed.  That may or may not be an acceptable distribution for whatever purpose is intended.  One might instead produce R with uniform distribution and then produce L with distribution uniform on the range 1 to R.  Not saying that would be better, just as an example of a decision that should be made.

Comment: @WhozCraig Your solution gives almost perfect uniform distribution of all the possible *[L;R]* segments. The only minor issue is that singular segments (i.e. when *L = R*) are two times less frequent than nonsingular ones. However, this is not a problem when both numbers are up to 10^18 anyway =)